# Addslashes / escape single quote in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm maintaining a piece of code that concatenates SQL queries like:

```
string sql = "SELECT* FROM table WHERE column = '" + value + "'";
```

Now it turned out that if **value** contains **'** characted it will break SQL Server text statement. I searched a bit for method similar to PHP addslashes, but without success. There's **Regex.Escape** but it didn't do the trick. Is there any other way to address that issue except calling **Replace** method on string?:

```
string sql = "SELECT* FROM table WHERE column = '" + value.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

Thanks,
Paweł

Comment: Do you absolutely _have_ to concatenate? Can't you use parameters instead?

Comment: A great deal of refactoring is required to do that....

Comment: Case in point why we need a "first do no harm" type of oath when we start coding...  That *great deal of refactoring* will help you immensely in the future.  Spend the cycles now and kill this technical debt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend don't use the string concatenation you should use the parameters instead look at the following example

```
// 1. declare command object with parameter
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "select * from Customers where city = @City", conn);
// 2. define parameters used in command object
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@City";
param.Value         = inputCity;
// 3. add new parameter to command object
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be using [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) and [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of building the query as you currently are.
As others have said, what you're doing leaves you wide open to injection attacks.

If you can't do that then as you say, Replace is as good an option as any.

Answer (score 3):

You are opening your code to a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack - use parametrized queries instead.

As a bonus, such escaping shenanigans will no longer be needed, as the libraries will take care of them for you.

Answer (score 1):

And this is a key reason why SQL parameters are generally recommended. If that's not an option, I think `String.Replace()` is as good as any other method.